# ASP.net MVC SimpleMembership

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, guid, simplemembership

I'm using SimpleMembership, and I've connected it to my User table, and everything worked fine. But when I've tried to change UserId from int to guid, I've got error:

```
Cannot convert type 'System.Guid' to 'int'
```

For these lines of code:

```
 WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.Email, model.Password,
 new
 {
     Name = model.Name,
     Surname = model.Surname,
     Gender = model.Gender,

 }
);
```

In tables webpages_OAuthMembership and  webpages_Membership I've changed UserId from int to uniqueidentifier (which represents guid) but hasn't helped.

So can I have guid for user Id and if I can, how ? 
And if I can't use guid can I use BIGINT ?

Comment: I don't believe it's supported (though I wish it was). You may be able to implement your own SimpleMembershipProvider that accepts GUIDs. http://forums.asp.net/t/1856517.aspx/1?ASP+NET+MVC+4+Simple+Membership

Comment: The following article indicates that Microsoft is working on a solution, as of January 2013. Does anybody have any workarounds yet? http://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/41201-asp-net-mvc/suggestions/3573751-use-generic-types-for-userid-in-simple-membership-

Comment: There is solution on link you posted, Erik Porter posted it in comments ;) Only other option is to to build your own provider. At least that's what I found so far

Answer (score 0):

The idea of the SimpleMembershipProvider is that it is very easy to implement as i usually works right out of the box. You have to get along with its user table, though. If you want to use your own user table and maybe some selfmade password encryption/decryption etc., you should create a CustomMembershipProvider. With that, you can customize everything to fit your existing environment or database.